# Swift Spotify API Error code 405 add to library?

Tags: swift, spotify

I am trying to add `Track` to a user's library using Spotify API but I am getting a 400 response status. I've tried this request with `Alamofire` and start getting `postCount` error because of `Spotify` header token ..

**here is the Part of Code :**

```
func spotify_addToLibrary()
{

    self.spotify_verifySession(completion:{ success , auth in

        if !success
        {
            return
        }

        let postString                  = "ids=[\"\(self.trackid)\"]"
        let url: NSURL                  = NSURL(string: "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks")!
        var request                     = URLRequest(url: url as URL)
            request.cachePolicy         = .useProtocolCachePolicy
            request.timeoutInterval     = 8000
            request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
            request.addValue("Bearer \(auth.session.accessToken!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            request.httpMethod = "post"
            request.httpBody   = postString.data(using: .utf8)

         URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, err in

                    if err == nil
                    {
                        print("Add to Library success \(String(describing: response))")

                    }else
                    {
                        print("Add to Library Error \(String(describing: err))")
                    }

                }.resume()
    })
}
```

And this is the Log:

```
Add to Library success Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x174c25d80> { URL: https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks } { status code: 405, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    "Cache-Control" = "private, max-age=0";
    "Content-Length" = 0;
    Date = "Fri, 08 Sep 2017 14:29:24 GMT";
    Server = nginx;
    "access-control-allow-credentials" = true;
    "access-control-allow-headers" = "Accept, Authorization, Origin, Content-Type";
    "access-control-allow-methods" = "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE";
    "access-control-max-age" = 604800;
    allow = "DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PUT";
} })
```

What did I miss there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTP error 405 means you are trying to use a method in your REST request that is not valid on the specific endpoint.

If you check the [documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/console/user%20library/) of the Spotify Web API, it clearly states that the valid HTTP verbs to be used for the `/me/tracks` endpoint are: `DELETE`, `GET` and `PUT`. `POST` is not allowed, hence the error.

Just change `request.httpMethod = "post"` to `request.httpMethod = "put"` and the error should be solved.

Some generic advice: don't use `Foundation` types when native Swift equivalents exist (`NSURL` instead of `URL`) and conform to the Swift naming convention, which is lower-camelCase for variable and function names (`spotify_addToLibrary` should be `spotifyAddToLibrary`). A timeout interval of 8000 **seconds** also seems to be quite unrealistic.

Comment: You're also not sending JSON data in the body of your request. Look into how to convert a String to JSON.